# MySQL Select from 3 tables where date varies

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to run a query to select information from a table where conditions on two others are met based on time and one other condition.

The tables are:

**Lead**

```
lead_id   lead_bname    lead_tname    lead_created
  1       ABC Stores    ABC            2015-06-01 12:20:50
  2       DEF Hutt      DEF            2015-07-13 13:52:06
```

**Lead Owner**

```
lead_owner_id    lead_id    staff_id    lead_owner_timestamp
      1             1         105        2015-06-01 12:20:50
      2             1         103        2015-06-01 12:20:51
      3             2         105        2015-07-13 13:52:06
```

**Lead Status**

```
lead_status_id    lead_id    status_ID    lead_status_timestamp
      1              1         54          2015-06-01 12:20:50
      2              1         56          2015-06-06 10:14:55
      3              2         54          2015-07-13 13:52:06
```

With a query I need to get the *lead_bname* and *lead_tname* where the timestamps (not created) are with a dynamic timeframe. (e.g. 2015-06-01 -> 2015-06-03) and then matches to a particular staff_id at that time even if earlier or later it has changed. The same again for the status.

I attempted the below, but I got a 0 result.

```
SELECT l.lead_id, lead_bname, lead_tname, lead_created 
FROM lead l, lead_owner o, lead_status s 
WHERE lead_owner_timestamp = ( 
     SELECT max(lead_owner_timestamp) 
     FROM lead_owner 
     WHERE lead_ID = l.lead_ID) 
AND ( lead_owner_timestamp <= '2015-06-01' AND lead_owner_timestamp >= '2015-06-03') 
AND staff_id = '103'
AND lead_status_timestamp = ( 
     SELECT max(lead_status_timestamp) 
     FROM lead_status WHERE lead_ID = l.lead_ID) 
AND status_ID = '54' 
AND ( lead_status_timestamp <= '2015-06-01' AND lead_status_timestamp >= '2015-06-03')
```

**Expected Result**

```
lead_bname    lead_tname    lead_created           status_id
ABC Stores    ABC           2015-06-01 12:20:50    54
```

This is because at between these two dates the lead was created and the status set at '54' and the staff_id was assigned as '103' as the latest entry.
If the staff was selected as '105' I would expect to receive a 0 result, which is still useful to me.

Really stuck on this one, imagining that I will require some Inner or Outer Joins on this, but it's a little beyond me, so hoping someone here can help out.

Comment: Can you add a result (as you expect it) from your sample data?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen added, hope this adds a little clarity

Comment: @SeánMcCabe I redid the query - let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, you need joins and some inner selects. Try this:

```
SELECT l.lead_bname, l.lead_tname, l.lead_created, ls.status_id
FROM lead l
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT lead_owner_id, lead_id, staff_id, lead_owner_timestamp
     FROM lead_owner
     WHERE lead_owner_timestamp = (SELECT MAX(lead_owner_timestamp) FROM lead_owner WHERE staff_id = 103)   
     AND lead_owner_timestamp >= '2015-06-01'
     AND lead_owner_timestamp <= '2015-06-03' 
     AND staff_id = 103
    ) lo ON l.lead_id = lo.lead_id
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT lead_status_id, lead_id, status_id, lead_status_timestamp 
     FROM lead_status
     WHERE lead_status_timestamp >= '2015-06-01' 
     AND lead_status_timestamp <= '2015-06-03'
     AND status_id = 54
    ) ls ON l.lead_id = ls.lead_id
```

**Notice that with this new revision there are *two* places that you need to change the staff id** when necessary - line 6 `WHERE staff_id = 103` and line 9 `AND staff_id = 103`. I created a test database with all the data you gave in it and it return the row you expected when the staff id is 103 and nothing when it is 105.

Comment: returned an empty result

Comment: The greater than and less than were backwards - I just fixed it. Try it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: That worked. It just needed a GROUP BY l.lead_id on the end to stop multiple of the same result. Just expanding on this, say I have a particular staff_id as stated in my attempted query above, how would that work. ie. staff_id = '103'

Comment: I edited my answer. The group by might throw things off - try the query with and without it to see what result set you actually want.

Comment: Not quite working. As whether I put in 103 or 105 for the staff id it comes back with the result, but I only wanted the latest based on the timestamps that much that date. This is why I tried to use "max" in my initial query.

Comment: Needing that max changes things quite a bit. The inner selects are now necessary. I've edited my query, give a try and let me know.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'lo.lead_owner_timestamp' in 'where clause'

Comment: It runs but returns an empty run, with or without the GROUP BY

Comment: Thought this had worked, but it only ever returns one result.

Comment: It returns exactly what you requested. What do you need different? What is a case that is is return null when it should be returning something else?

Answer (score 0):

When you are check date only part must be convert datetime to date like this

```
SELECT l.lead_bname, l.lead_tname, l.lead_created, ls.status_id
FROM lead l
INNER JOIN lead_owner lo ON l.lead_id = lo.lead_id
INNER JOIN lead_status ls ON l.lead_id = ls.lead_id
WHERE (
    CONVERT(lo.lead_owner_timestamp,DATE) <= '2015-06-01'
    AND CONVERT(lo.lead_owner_timestamp,DATE) >= '2015-06-03'
)
AND (
    CONVERT(ls.lead_status_timestamp,DATE) <= '2015-06-01' 
    AND CONVERT(ls.lead_status_timestamp,DATE) >= '2015-06-03'
) 
AND ls.status_id = 54
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lo.lead_owner_timestamp) <= '2015-06-01' AND convert(date,lo.lead_owner_time' at line 6

Comment: You are use mssql so convert function syntex change now check it

Comment: Works the same as MrMadsen answer, once the > and < are changed to the right way round and a Group By is added. This one again doesnt allow selection based on a particular staff_id (even if the result returns 0 [as this I need to know])